# Как передать переменную с одного файла в php в другой php

Tags: php, html, sql

У меня есть скрипт написанный на php, который выводит с базы данных комментарии, я хочу реализовать удаление комментариев, но для этого мне нужно с файла include_data.php передать id комментария в файл delete.php, чтобы создать запрос на удаление комментария с базы данных, а так же хочется, чтобы когда я нажимаю на кнопку удалить, высвечивалось подтверждения, для избежания случайных нажатий, подскажите пожалуйста.

Вот скрипт:

```
<?php 

    include 'connect.php';
    
    $result = mysqli_query($link, " SELECT * FROM `coments` ");
    while ($field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $id = $field['id'];
        $delete = "<a href='delete_base.php'>Удалить</a>";
        echo 'Отзыв от ' . $field['name_coment'] . '<br><br> Коментарий: <br>' . $field['coment'] . "<br>" . $field['date_coments'] . '<br>' . $delete . '<hr>';

    }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все очень просто, добавьте в тело Вашей ссылки на удаление `GET`-параметр `id` удаляемой записи.

```php
  ...
  $delete = "<a href='delete_base.php?id='.$id.'>Удалить</a>";
  ...
```

После чего в `delete_base.php` Вы сможете получить этот параметр из глобального массива `$_GET`

```php
  ...
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  ...
```

Естественно в самом `delete_base.php` проверьте что это параметр передан, что запись в БД с таким номером существует. А также, если у Вас есть какое-то разграничение прав пользователей, проверьте имеет ли право текущий пользователь удалять запись с указанным `id`, например, в ситуации когда пользователь может удалять только записи создатель которых он сам.